# Return properties are null value when I get by Id

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, graphql, graphql-java

I've just create a new spring boot application with GraphQL + MongoDB. I can retrieve an array from database, but querying by id does not work. Property is null. But I see the data correctly while debugging. It like GraphQL is not capable to match the query with the value return.

I'm new at using GraphQL, it's probably little details...

Schema GraphQL

```
schema {
    query: Query
}

type Query {
    datasets: [Dataset]
    dataset(id: String): Dataset
}

type Dataset {
    id: String
    name: String!
}
```

Dataset class look like this:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Document(collection = "datasets")
public class Dataset {
    private ObjectId id;
    private String name;
}
```

When I query with:

```
{
    datasets{
        name
    }
}
```

I get this:

```
{
    "datasets": [
        {
            "name": "My Dataset"
        }
    ]
}
```

But when I query with:

```
{
    dataset(id: "5dab4ec97ff755534437c8bc"){
        name
    }
}
```

I get this:

```
{
    "dataset": null
}
```

The id is ok:
[image]

Comment: Because you defined response like that array of Dataset and object Dataset so you got null value If get only name then you write  Dataset{name} then get object of  Dataset{ name: "My Dataset"}

Comment: What graphql framework are you using ? I guess it is graphql-java-tools from the questions you asked before. If yes , let 's mention it in the question.